# Converting NSData representation of UIImage to NSImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uiimage, nsimage

is there a way to use an NSData that has been created from a UIImage to create an NSImage? I already have the NSData representation of a UIImage and it is sent via TCP/IP to a MacOSX application... Now I need to convert the NSData received to an NSImage. What is the most efficient way to do this?

I'm using:

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (UIImage *image);
```

To convert the UIImage to NSData before it is sent over the network.

Comment: Why don't you show us how you save a UIImage object in an NSData object?

Comment: @ElTomato edited the question as requested :)

Answer (score 1):

You can following method to create `NSImage` from `NSData`

```
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data
```

Use it as follow

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

As per documentation

> The data object containing the image data. The data can be in any format that OS X supports, including PDF, PICT, EPS, or any number of bitmap data formats.

Comment: But will this take into consideration that the NSData is a UIImage representation and not an NSImage representation? I don't think so...

Comment: Your question says "NSData that has been created from a UIImage". Above method will create NSImage from "NSData representation of UIImage"

Comment: Yes, and as far as I know the UIImage has different NSData representation than the NSData. The bits have different endianess afaik

Comment: If you say a UIImage object has a different NSData representation, then I don't see there is anything that you can do about it except that I may have a similar topic there before.